# Change fonts everywhere in OS

Tags: ubuntu, fonts

I am using elementary OS which is based on Ubuntu Linux. I would like to change my fonts everywhere text is displayed on OS. Is there a way to do it, or am I too hopeful?

Comment: It sure is possible but a bit too general to get a good answer.  What problems have you faced so far or which section were you not able to find a solution to get a different font?

Comment: I want to change the fonts that come pre-defined with the OS. How would I go about it?

Comment: Although this question is on-topic here, you're more likely to get help on [elementaryos.se]. If you choose to repost there, please delete your question here, or else don't repost but flag your question and ask a moderator to migrate.

Comment: There's no way to change the font *everywhere* (e.g. it wouldn't make sense for a WYSIWYG word processor to use that font, web pages can specify a non-default font, some things call for a monospace font, …), but there's probably a way to change the font for normal text applications that use the elementary theme.

Comment: You can change your system fonts. If your trying to systematically modify all your fonts, it would be difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try elementary tweaks for do that, you can install it with this common :

> sudo apt install software-properties-common
>
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:philip.scott/elementary-tweaks
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install elementary-tweaks

Elementary Tweaks will show on system settings

Answer (score 2):

You can install the application *dconf-editor* with your terminal and
there you can change these setting.
Type in your terminal...

```
sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

Then, after installation finished open *dconf-editor* and go to

> org > gnome > desktop > interface

Now on the right side there is a point called 'font-name' and after that its defined with 'Open Sans 9' by default. This is your default system font.
Change the number to 10 for example and you see the affect immediately.
The font for terminal or scratch-text-editor are separately.

For terminal go to...

> org > pantheon > terminal > settings

For scratch-text-editor got to...

> org > pantheon > scratch > settings